# Can't close PCL visualizer

Tags: point-cloud-library

I am writing a program to record and store pointclouds. Part of the programs function to observe the recorded clouds, for this I use the PCL visualizer. The problem is that if I close the visualizers window the window just stops, but won't close. I tried calling the close() method, but nothing. I read that this was a problem before VTK 8.0, but I use 8.1 and the problem is still there. I also use PCL 1.9.1 and Ubuntu 18.04.
Anyone has a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It will help your fellow coders if you provide a code example so we can see exactly what you mean!

Comment: Interesting.. I had this problem from a long time, I got used to it. Better ask this question in Github issues, probably PCL contributor has solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `wasStopped()` instead of close();

After creating your viewer object:

```
while (!viewer.wasStopped ())
       {
        viewer.spinOnce ();
      }
```

Comment: This does not work for me. The viewer window opens but does not close. I have to close it manually.

Comment: It might be related to this issue: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/172